# Go into one side of screen and come out on other side?

Tags: c#, xna

Could someone give me advice on how to have the player go through one side of the screen, and come out the opposite side in XNA C#?

If you need an example, just look at Super Mario Bros. 2, if you go into the right side you'll come out the left, for example.

Comment: this is definitely not the place for that question, and what you are asking is not so much complex as it is a lot of code and transitions.  try asking on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/?as=1 and provide some sample code.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon: Is correct, also note that you have to determine whether you want to show an object on both sides at once, or only one (that changes where the transition happens)

Answer (score 3):

I am going to respond at the highest level, there is a lot more to this than I am letting on.

Normally you stop the character from moving past the barrier of the screen, if you are using such a system you need to instead track them outside of the viewport, and know when to wrap them around. This could either be when the character completely disappears off the screen, or the moment any part of him disappears from the screen.

Then it becomes handling the special cases of drawing when he is partially off the screen, and moving him over to the other side once the transition has completed (or any time in between if that makes sense for your implementation, for instance the character could be considered on the other side once 50% moved off the screen).

Also note that I focus on characters, but any visible elements will have to know about these situations, even if they can't travel the same way. For instance if you are half on both sides you may be vulnerable on both sides. All of these are design decisions you need to make.

With regards to the technical implementation, that is above and beyond what we can do for you here, refinement is something we can do, but creation should come from you. (And is so heavily dependent on your other code that anything we made would just be an example and not directly usable).